# How to convert KiCAD pcb file to HPGL/1 for use with old HP plotter?

Tags: pcb, kicad, conversion, plot

I intend to use my HP 7475A for directly plotting etch-resistant ink onto a pcb. My problem is that, while KiCAD has an option for HPGL exports, it only generates HPGL/2 compatible files. Those make heavy use of things like the polygon mode or a variable line width, which are all not supported by my relatively *dumb* plotter.

I already thought about using a slicer for 3d printers, as the task of filling out shapes with a single-width stroke is the same. Unfortunately I can't find a way of converting the resulting G-code back to HPGL/1 code. I also tried to use Inkscape but only ended up with an outline of my traces without any infill.

Comment: There is a [proposal](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/kicad/+spec/support-for-basic-hpgl) to support basic HPGL.

Comment: Well yeah. That proposal was added by me. I thought as a last resort I could dive into the code and do it myself but I think that'd be a serious investment of time.

Comment: You'd be welcome to join us on the #KiCad channel on Freenode.